# How to set a Git repository when creating a job in Jenkins from a Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, git, release-management, groovy

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins server with Groovy script:

```
def repository = 'git@somerepo'
import hudson.tasks.Shell;

job = Jenkins.instance.createProject(FreeStyleProject, 'TestJob')
job.setDescription("Some description")
job.displayName = 'SomeTestJob(TESTING groovy)'

job.scm = new hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM(repository)
job.save()
```

Now I need to set a repo branch - How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963309/how-create-and-configure-a-new-jenkins-job-using-groovy

Comment: def repository = 'git@somerepo'
    import hudson.tasks.Shell;
    
    job = Jenkins.instance.createProject(FreeStyleProject, 'TestJob')
    job.setDescription("Some description")
    job.displayName = 'SomeTestJob(TESTING groovy)'

    job.scm = new hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM(repository)
    job.scm.branches = [new BranchSpec('*/master')];
    job.save()

Thanks a lot Michael Durrant for giving that link ! This is strange - i've seen before but didn't manage to use the answers as i only noticed the jobDsl code fragments that time...

Comment: Please post this as an answer. This Q&A pops up in the unanswered section while is has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def repository = 'git@somerepo' 
import hudson.tasks.Shell
job = Jenkins.instance.createProject(FreeStyleProject, 'TestJob')
job.setDescription("Some description") 
job.displayName = 'SomeTestJob(TESTING groovy)' 
job.scm = new hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM(repository) 
job.scm.branches = [new BranchSpec('*/master')]
job.save()
```

Thanks a lot Michael Durrant for giving that link !